# Pandas Data-frame, Using .apply(lambda x :...) but depends on last x value

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I want to have a quicker way to do the below in a column of DataFrame.
Now I can only do this in for loop, and it is quite slow. but I cannot depends on last (x) in using lambda!

```
for i in range(len(Zscore_list)):
    if len(Pos_list) != 0:
        if Pos_list[i-1] == 1:
            if Zscore_list[i] < -Thre2:
                Pos_list.append(1)
            else:
                Pos_list.append(0)
        elif Pos_list[i-1] == -1:
            if Zscore_list[i] > Thre2:
                Pos_list.append(-1)
            else:
                Pos_list.append(0)
        elif Pos_list[i-1] == 0:
            if Zscore_list[i] > Thre:
                Pos_list.append(-1)
            elif Zscore_list[i] < -Thre:
                Pos_list.append(1)
            else:
                Pos_list.append(0) 
    else:
        if Zscore_list[i] > Thre:
             Pos_list.append(-1)
        elif Zscore_list[i] < -Thre:
            Pos_list.append(1)
        else:
            Pos_list.append(0)
```

Comment: Does there are any way to do it in lambda? similar to dfc['D_i'] = dfc['D_i'].apply(lambda x: x if x>0 else 0)

Comment: Can you provide an example input and the expected output?

Comment: For example, I have a column price [1,5,9,10,9,5,3,1,0,-3,-4,-10] which is a time series of Data. I want to go -1 position when price >= 10, -1 position when price <=-10. However, if i go inside the position, i must wait for price = 0 to flat the position. So, the result will like this [0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,1].

Comment: Nice question - but it only became clear due to your explanation in the comment

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more *pythonic* ways to do this - but here is one possible solution:

```
zlist = [1,5,9,10,9,5,3,1,0,-3,-4,-10]

df = pd.DataFrame(zlist_series, columns = ["Z"])
df["Change_Point"] = df["Z"].apply(lambda x: int(abs(x) >= 10 or x == 0)) 
df["Change_Point_Is_Odd"] = df.Change_Point.cumsum().apply(lambda x: int(bool(x%2)))
df["Sign_Of_Change"] = df.Z.apply(lambda x: math.copysign(int(bool(abs(x))), x)) 
df["P"] = df.Change_Point_Is_Odd * df.Sign_Of_Change 
df.P = df.P.astype('int')

''' This is the output
     Z  Change_Point  Sign_Of_Change  Change_Point_Is_Odd  P
0    1             0             1.0                    0  0
1    5             0             1.0                    0  0
2    9             0             1.0                    0  0
3   10             1             1.0                    1  1
4    9             0             1.0                    1  1
5    5             0             1.0                    1  1
6    3             0             1.0                    1  1
7    1             0             1.0                    1  1
8    0             1             0.0                    0  0
9   -3             0            -1.0                    0  0
10  -4             0            -1.0                    0  0
11 -10             1            -1.0                    1 -1
'''
```

Comment: There are a few assumptions in this solution - most notably that there is always a zero between the positive and negative threshold values in the `Z` column. If this is not always the case, then the solution needs to be modified slightly.